# SimpleXMLElement to PHP Array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

Variable `$d` comes from `file_get_contents` function to a URL.

```
$answer = @new SimpleXMLElement($d);
```

Below is output of the `print_r($answer)`:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [Amount] => 2698
  [Status] => OK
  [State] => FL
  [Country] => USA
)
```

How can I retrieve value of each element and add to an array? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `$answer` can already work as an array. You can do this if you want put it in a real array,

```
$array = array();
foreach($answer as $k => $v) {
  $array[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: I can't iterate through a SimpleXMLElement object in the following way

Answer (score 65):

In this simple case type casting will also work:

```
$my_array = (array)$answer
```

Comment: This is not recursive.

Answer (score 56):

This should work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: I just tested and this works. Even does it recursively, which is great. I do worry about what will happen in the event of a non-UTF-8 character, though. The `json_encode` and `json_decode` methods tend to choke when they come across a non-UTF-8 character. Wrapping in a `try...catch` would be wise, though I don't know if there would be a way to handle it properly (i.e. encode to UTF-8) without writing a custom parser.

Comment: Both `json_encode` and `http_build_query` seem to have issues interpreting `<![CDATA[` `]]>` tags. It seems both functions determine them to be empty objects, in which case `http_build_query` ignores it completely.

Answer (score 8):

I have a problem with this function because typecasting every XML child to an array can be problematic when the text is between `CDATA` tags.

I fixed this by checking if the result of the typecasting to an array is empty. If so typecast it to a string and you will get a proper result.

Here is my modified version with `CDATA` support:

```
function SimpleXML2ArrayWithCDATASupport($xml)
{   
    $array = (array)$xml;

    if (count($array) === 0) {
        return (string)$xml;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_object($value) || strpos(get_class($value), 'SimpleXML') === false) {
            continue;
        }
        $array[$key] = SimpleXML2ArrayWithCDATASupport($value);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: I found that `json_encode` and `http_build_query` suffer from the exact same symptoms, so this approach is the most reliable.

Comment: It's still ignoring CDATA fields. I had to do `$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml',SimpleXMLElement::class,LIBXML_NOCDATA);` but then your function wasn't needed anymore, I could just do `json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml),true);`

Comment: Sadly, still doesn't work with namespace data :/

Answer (score 1):

this function parse a xml simpleXML recursive to array recursive

```
function SimpleXML2Array($xml){
    $array = (array)$xml;

    //recursive Parser
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if(strpos(get_class($value),"SimpleXML")!==false){
            $array[$key] = SimpleXML2Array($value);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: i have a problem with this function because typecasting every xml child to an array can give you a problem when the text is between CDATA tags.