# Reading PHP array output in a loop

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this output when reading an XML file.

http://pastebin.com/NfNHBaHt

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [GetAllDomains] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [DomainDetail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [DomainName] => domain1.com
                            [DomainNameID] => 153033597
                            [expiration-date] => 3/1/2017 2:23:56 PM
                            [lockstatus] => Locked
                            [AutoRenew] => Yes
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [DomainName] => domain2.com
                            [DomainNameID] => 153043233
                            [expiration-date] => 5/25/2017 5:45:00 PM
                            [lockstatus] => Not Locked
                            [AutoRenew] => Yes
                        )

                )

            [domaincount] => 2
            [UserRequestStatus] => DomainBox
        )

    [Command] => GETALLDOMAINS
    [APIType] => API
    [Language] => eng
    [ErrCount] => 0
    [ResponseCount] => 0
    [MinPeriod] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [MaxPeriod] => 10
    [Server] => SJL0VWRESELL_T1
    [Site] => eNom
    [IsLockable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [IsRealTimeTLD] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [TimeDifference] => +0.00
    [ExecTime] => 0.094
    [Done] => true
    [RequestDateTime] => 5/25/2015 9:47:21 AM
    [debug] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

the above output is being shown by using the `print_r` function in PHP

how can i loop through the array of `DomainDetail` in PHP using a `foreach` loop

i tried using `print_r($xml->DomainDetail);` and `print_r($xml["DomainDetail"]);`

but nothing is being shown using this `print_r`

Comment: Convert the simleXMLObject to an array -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($xml->GetAllDomains->DomainDetail as $domainDetail) {
    echo $domainDetail->DomainName, "\n";
    echo $domainDetail->DomainNameID, "\n";
    echo $domainDetail->{'expiration-date'}, "\n";
    // etc..
}
```