# Foreach XML If Loop Only Returning First Nodes

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the `SKU`'s of each `MerchantFulfillmentID` that has the value `MFN` in it.

Here is my xml:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
<SettlementReport>
    <Refund>
        <Fulfillment>
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>MFN</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <AdjustedItem>
                <SKU>1MFNSKU1</SKU>
            </AdjustedItem>
        </Fulfillment>
    </Refund>
    <Refund>
        <Fulfillment>  
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>AFN</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <AdjustedItem>
                <SKU>1AFNSKU1</SKU>
            </AdjustedItem>
        </Fulfillment>
    </Refund>
            <Refund>
        <Fulfillment>
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>MFN</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <AdjustedItem>
                <SKU>2MFNSKU2</SKU>
            </AdjustedItem>
        </Fulfillment>
    </Refund>
            <Refund>
        <Fulfillment>  
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>AFN</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <AdjustedItem>
                <SKU>2AFNSKU2</SKU>
            </AdjustedItem>
        </Fulfillment>
    </Refund>
</SettlementReport>
</Message>';
```

And my PHP

```
$xmlload = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xmlload->Message->SettlementReport->Refund->Fulfillment as $ful) {
if ($ful->MerchantFulfillmentID == 'MFN') {
    echo $ful->MerchantFulfillmentID;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $ful->AdjustedItem->SKU;
}
}
```

My result is

> MFN
>
> 1MFNSKU1

Which is only taking the result from the first iteration it finds. How can I make it so that every instance of `MFN` will echo out the `SKU`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would create an array from your XML as below.

```
$xmlToString   = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xmlToArray = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xmlToString), TRUE);

print_r($xmlToArray);
```

This will print out;

```
Array
(
    [SettlementReport] => Array
        (
            [Refund] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Fulfillment] => Array
                                (
                                    [MerchantFulfillmentID] => MFN
                                    [AdjustedItem] => Array
                                        (
                                            [SKU] => 1MFNSKU1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Fulfillment] => Array
                                (
                                    [MerchantFulfillmentID] => AFN
                                    [AdjustedItem] => Array
                                        (
                                            [SKU] => 1AFNSKU1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Fulfillment] => Array
                                (
                                    [MerchantFulfillmentID] => MFN
                                    [AdjustedItem] => Array
                                        (
                                            [SKU] => 2MFNSKU2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Fulfillment] => Array
                                (
                                    [MerchantFulfillmentID] => AFN
                                    [AdjustedItem] => Array
                                        (
                                            [SKU] => 2AFNSKU2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then do a foreach on "$xmlToArray".

```
    foreach($xmlToArray['SettlementReport']['Refund'] as $ful)
    {
        if( $ful['Fulfillment']['MerchantFulfillmentID'] == 'MFN')
        {
            echo $ful['Fulfillment']['MerchantFulfillmentID'];
            echo $ful['Fulfillment']['AdjustedItem']['SKU'];

        }
    }
```

Related artile: [Converting a SimpleXML Object to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array)

Comment: I also added the foreach example in the answer ;)

Comment: I appreciate the help! Array's do make it easier to work with. I am working on localhost and had to add `['Message']` to make it `foreach($xmlToArray['Message']['SettlementReport']['Refund'] as $ful)` otherwise I got an `Undefined index: SettlementReport` -- but it works well! Thank you again.