# how correct read array from xml with json convert in php array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, converters

how correct read  array  was from xml with  json convert in php array?

```
     <php?
    $xmlfile = file_get_contents('data.xml');
    $ob= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
    $json  = json_encode($ob);
    $configData = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach($configData["id"] as $configData)
    {
    echo $configData["name"];
    echo $configData["image"];
     echo $configData["id"];

    }

?>
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach  in /data.php on line 10

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Try using simplexml_load_file function. I have always found success in using this whenever you are dealing with xml files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the ids, you should stick to using SimpleXML...

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");

foreach ( $xmlfile->smarza as $data )   {
    echo $data->id.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This loads the file using `simplexml_load_file()` and then loops in the `foreach()` it goes over each `<smarza>` element (using `$xmlfile->smarza`).  The access the `<id>` element using `$data->id`.