# Transform array into normal array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, parsing, curl

My Array looks like this

```html
Array ( 
  [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [0] => Car String
  ) 
)
```

And should look like this:

```html
Array ( 
      title => Car String 
      )
```

I got this array by doing curl_exec a xml file and changed it with "new SimpleXMLElement".
Every solution i could find didn't work.

So how can i transform the array? Or is there a more efficient way to get a xml with http header options?

Comment: show us the relevant code and a sample of the XML, please.

Comment: duplicate [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your array, you need to cast the `SimpleXMLElement Object` into the desired type. In your case you need to cast into a `string` element.

There is the simple way to do that :

```php
$xmlString = "<element><title>Car String</title></element>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$array = [
    'title' => (string)$xml->title;
];
```

or

```php
$xmlString = "<element><title>Car String</title></element>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$array = [
    'title' => $xml->title->__toString();
];
```