# how to get SimpleXMLElement Object to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

how to get SimpleXMLElement Object to array in PHP my SimpleXMLElement Object response code is

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 160040
        )

    [error_msg] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 验证码超出同模板同号码天发送上限
        )

    [smsMessageSid] => 
)
```

Comment: You can just access the items using `$xml->error_code` and `$xml->error_msg` with whatever your SimpleXML variable is called instead of `$xml`

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726487/simplexmlelement-to-php-array

Comment: You've tagged your question with `json` - is this actually about how to convert a SimpleXML object to JSON?