# How can I save a XML file (sourced from API) at runtime?

Tags: php, xml, api

I am needing to get data from my online CRM to my website. The data is sourced from an API, which returns a long list of XML code. I then need to process this XML using PHP to put it on my website (only part of it is needed).

I know XSLT is preferred over PHP for XML processing but I haven't learnt XSLT as yet (getting to that next week) so will use PHP for now.

Just need to know how to save the API's XML file to my server at runtime so I can reference it in my PHP?

Comment: XSLT is simply a means for applying styling transformations to XML.  This has nothing to do with what you are looking for.  Just capture your XML and write it to a file.

Comment: You can use DOM+Xpath to extract data from a XML into PHP. (think SQL) or an XSLT to transform the XML into a different output (think template). If you just want to save the XML, just save the data string/stream to a file. Please provide some source to narrow your problem it down.

Comment: Erm, are you looking for... `file_put_contents()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of PHP's painstaking XML parsing script, you may want to check out `json_decode()` which can convert an XML object into an associative array.

eg. `$data = json_decode($xmlData, true);`

check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6534234/668703 for a complete example.

As for saving the content on to your server, check out `file_put_contents` (https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents), just keep in mind that you'll need a *string* to store into the file.

Comment: thanks :) both these answers have been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DOMDocument`'s [load](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) and [save](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) methods.

Comment: thanks :) both these answers have been a great help :)