# Reducing arrays of floats from datetime

Tags: php

Basically, when reducing the arrays it's adding up the number in the hours section incorrectly.

I've got the following function

```
function reduceHours($carry, $item)
{
    if (! array_key_exists($item["recruiter"], $carry))
        $carry[$item["recruiter"]] = 0;
    $carry[$item["recruiter"]] += $item["hours"];
    return $carry;
}
```

Here is the original Array it's reducing

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [orderId] => 3988445
    [status] => filled
    [shiftStartTime] => 2019-01-11T07:00:00
    [shiftEndTime] => 2019-01-11T15:30:00
    [tempId] => 57921
    [firstName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lastName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [clientId] => 1543
    [clientName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [regionName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [orderSpecialty] => School
    [orderCertification] => SLP
    [floor] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [shiftNumber] => 1
    [note] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [payrollNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lessLunchMin] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [dateTimeCreated] => 2018-08-06T17:03:34
    [takenBy] => 480
    [bookedByUserId] => 480
    [orderTypeId] => 1
    [orderType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [city] => Media
    [state] => xx
    [zipCode] => xxxxx
    [orderSourceID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [orderSourceName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lt_orderID] => 0
    [dateTimeModified] => 2018-08-06T17:03:34
    [subjectID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [subject] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )
    [Recruiter] => Name
    [Hours] => 8
)
```

which reduces to arrays that look like this

```
(
    [Max ] => 23.8
    [Allison ] => 5.3
    [Travis ] => 74.4
    [Alyssa ] => 12
    [total] => 6703.83
)
```

It works, but I get the wrong totals. The original variable is a date time interval like this

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 7
    [i] => 30
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

This is based on time so it's base 60. As you can see from the first array I'm getting 4's and 8's and sometimes more than 2 decimal places.

If you need any more code or results posted please let me know.

Comment: Sure that's all the code?

Comment: use `var_dump($item)` at the start of the reducer to see what you're dealing with

Comment: Can you please post of small amount of data from your array before the reduce - so we can verify how the `hours` key set. This will tell us if the error is from the converting datatime to hour side of the code or from the reduce function side of the code

Comment: Posted the original array. I will var dump at the beginning of the reducer. It basically sends an empty array() to start and then appends the recruiters name if it's not already there, if it is it adds the hours to a running total.

Comment: Can you please verify that all the `hours` values are integers and not float? Or add log print in the reduce function for `$item["hours"]` and see if you get any non integers

Comment: Also, the hours number is found from this `$startLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftStartTime);
        $start = $startLong->format('Y-m-d');
        $endLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftEndTime);
        $end = $endLong->format('Y-m-d');$shiftHours = $startLong->diff($endLong);`

Comment: Apparently, they are floats `array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  ["Cynthia "]=>
  float(2)
}
array(2) {
  ["Cynthia "]=>
  float(2)
  ["Brittany "]=>
  float(2)
}
array(3) {
  ["Cynthia "]=>
  float(2)
  ["Brittany "]=>
  float(2)
  ["Sarah "]=>
  float(1.15)`

Comment: 1. what were "Sarah" hours so it gets `1,15`? 2. From `$shiftHours` which is `DateInterval` object -> how do you extract the hours? (which will be set eventually in the `hours` key)

Comment: It was an hour and fifteen minutes. $shiftHours = `$startLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftStartTime); $start = $startLong->format('Y-m-d'); $endLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftEndTime); $end = $endLong->format('Y-m-d');$shiftHours = $startLong->diff($endLong);`

Comment: Ok, it's because of it treating them as floats. When I get 1.15 and 1.45 it adds it and gets 2.6. So that makes sense now. Any way to have it treat it as times? 1.15 would really equal 1.25 and 1.45 would be 1.75.

Comment: @mobirae - I posted 2 ways - I think you should go with the second one but it up to you . And I truly mean about editing your question - if you do it right you enable people to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem was of using [dateinterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object to get the time difference. But them you just add the hours and minutes up but this is "base 60" (as 60 minutes in 1 hour) so you cannot add them up with `+`.

**Example**: 1 hour and 15 minute (`1.15`) plus 1 hour and 45 minute (`1.45`) are `2.6` numerically speaking but 3 hours (as from your comment).

In order to solve that you need to convert to numerical. You can use the following function:

```
function convertToDecimal($hours) {
    $parts = explode('.', (string)$hours);
    $min = (count($parts) == 2) ? $parts[1] / 60 : 0;
    return $parts[0] + $min;
}
```

when calling `convertToDecimal(1.15)` will return `1.25`. add that to you reduce function as:

```
carry[$item["recruiter"]] += convertToDecimal($item["hours"]);
```

Hint - asking question properly is not easy task - now that you have your solution try edit your question so it will include all (and **only**) the data needed to unnderstand your problem and reproduce it.

Better solution include change the way you extract the time difference. Consider the following method:

```
$shiftStartTime = "2019-01-11T07:00:00";
$shiftEndTime = "2019-01-11T15:15:00";

$startLong = (new DateTime($shiftStartTime))->getTimestamp();
$endLong = (new DateTime($shiftEndTime))->getTimestamp();;

echo ($endLong - $startLong) / (60 * 60);
```

This will give you `8.25` as you counting the second and not setting the hours using DateInterval.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I really appreciate all your guys help, apparently I'm bad at asking questions. I'll figure it out though. One more question if you don't mind, this is my mistake though, apparently there is shifts that are ten minutes into the hour, would this account for that? I get this `[Gretchen ] => 7.6666666666667
    [Alexandra ] => 7.5
    [Lindsey ] => 16
    [Jeanine ] => 9
    [Michael ] => 6
    [Alicia ] => 7
    [Max ] => 24.333333333333`

Comment: Ok let me change the way I get the difference before making more changes.

Comment: Yes - both of the method are fine with 10 minute (even 3 minute) - up to you t o choose if you want to slice to 2 decimal point only

Comment: Got it, I guess what they used to do was round it to either the top of the hour or half past. So every recruiters hours was either a full number or X.5